# Como hacer para que mi aplicación con Ionic y Firebase, funcione sin conexión/offline

Tags: firebase, ionic, angular

estoy realizando una aplicación con Ionic que muestra unos simples datos traídos desde Firebase, mi problema es que solo funciona con conexión a Internet.

Me gustaría saber que tecnología o método utilizar para que los datos puedan ser vistos sin conexión, por ejemplo que se guarde en la cache del móvil o algo parecido.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes ser mas especifico?, ¿Que datos quieres guardar?, ¿Que has hecho hasta ahora? ¿Estas usando algún plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Revisa esta documentación, solo es cuestión de habilitar la persistencia: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

Si estás utilizando Angular>2 te recomiendo utilizar el módulo angularfire2 (en caso de que no lo tengas ya):
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/offline-data.md

De manera que solo harías lo siguiente en tu imports del NgModule:

```
AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence()
```